# Generic Type headache: Trouble passing in type when Generic Type inherits from multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, generics

I'm getting the error

```
The type GenericObject<ISomeInterface> must be convertible to <GenericObject<GenericObject<ISomeInterface>> 
in order to use it as parameter <T> in the generic class Wrapper<T>
```

Classes in question

```
public abstract class GenericObject<T> : ReactiveObject where T: class, ISomeInterface

public class SpecificSubObject: GenericObject<SpecificSubObject>, ISomeInterface {}

//T = any potential SpecificSubObject
public class Wrapper<T> : ReactiveObject, ISomeInterface where T : GenericObject<T>, ISomeInterface {}

//View.xaml.cs
public partial class View
{
  public Wrapper<GenericObject<ISomeInterface>> SomeWrapper {get;set;}
}
```

Is there some way (without making my View class generic (as partial classes cannot be generic)) to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a second parameter for Wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper<T,P> : ReactiveObject, ISomeInterface 
      where T : GenericObject<P> 
      where P : class, ISomeInterface
{...}
```

It should be inferred by compiler, so View will stay the same.